# Why my Delete button in gridview not hitting RowCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have unique problem. Delete button within gridview not working, it doesn't hit Row commnand event. I tried in debugging but not hitting row command event at all. Why ?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdViewTrainingsCourses" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="grdViewTrainingsCourses_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="grdViewTrainingsCourses_RowCommand"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CC99" DataKeyNames="pk_TrainingsCourses_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive scrollable">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_TrainingsCourses_ID" HeaderText="S.No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonalInfoName" HeaderText="Employee Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingsCoursesCourseTitle" HeaderText="Course Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingsCoursesInstituteName" HeaderText="Institute Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingsCoursesInstituteAddress" HeaderText="Institute Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingsCoursesFromDate" HeaderText="From " />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingsCoursesToDate" HeaderText="To" />

        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="cmdEdit" HeaderText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/delete.png" CommandName="cmdDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you Sure ?');" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
if (e.CommandName == "cmdDelete")
{

    MngTrainingsCourses.DeleteTrainingsCourses(TrainingsCoursesID);

    MngAudits.InsertAuditsInfo("Data deleted from" + " " + "TrainingsCourses", MngAudits.UserMacAddress, MngAudits.UserIPAddress, UserID);

    //LoadTraningsCourses();

    ActivateTrainingsCourses_Tab();

    int PersonalInfoID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PersonalInfoID"]);
    if (PersonalInfoID != 0)
    {
        LoadTrainingsCoursesByPersonalInfoID(PersonalInfoID);
    }
    else
    {
        LoadTrainingsCourses();
    }


    ShowMsgBox("Record Deleted Successfully");

}
```

please help me It has wasted a lot of my time

Comment: in your .cs file: int selectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex; use this

Comment: done and i also changed my code to <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/delete.png" CommandName="cmdDelete" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" ItemStyle-Width="25px" /> this and worked

Comment: Good job! Next time don't forget about this)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also link button instead of Image Button

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="✖ Delete" CommandName="cmdDelete"  CssClass="gvwdelete" ForeColor="Red" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete this record?');"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed delete coloumn to this instead of template and worked

```
<asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/delete.png" CommandName="cmdDelete" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" ItemStyle-Width="25px" />
```